# pushing docker image to registery of docker on a different host machine

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have two computers both have docker, I want to keep my docker image I made to the other host the does not connect to internet but is on local LAN.

so this is my machine (I use hello-world image example)

```
macHost:~ ciasto$ docker tag hello-world 192.168.0.6:5000/hello-world
```

then I try `docker push  192.168.0.6:5000/hello-world`

but this throws error:

```
The push refers to a repository [192.168.0.6:5000/hello-world]
Get https://192.168.0.6:5000/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.0.6:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

so I tried without 5000 port.

```
$ docker push 192.168.0.6/hello-world-2
```

that too throw same error:

```
The push refers to a repository [192.168.0.6/hello-world-2]
Get https://192.168.0.6/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.0.6:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Seems like port 5000 is not open on 192.168.0.6

Comment: @Alex Karshin how to find out if its really port 5000 or some other port?

Comment: How did you run the registry on 192.168.0.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) is a specific piece of software; you can't directly `docker push` an image to another system.

The best workflow is almost certainly to write a `Dockerfile` that describes how to build your image.  This is a simple text file, not totally unlike a shell script, that you'd typically add to your source code repository.  Then on the other system you could check out the repository and run `docker build` and get a functionally equivalent image.

If you have a semi-isolated network you can always run your own registry.  Say you set up your local DNS such that the host name `my-registry.local` resolves to 192.168.0.123; then you can `docker tag` your local images as `my-registry.local/me/imagename`, `docker push` them from one system, and `docker pull` them from the other.

The lowest-maintenance, least-reproducible, highest-long-term-effort path is to [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) the image on the first system, `scp` or otherwise transfer it to the second system, and then [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it there.  If you're motivated, you can even do it with one step

```
docker save me/imagename | ssh elsewhere docker load
```

You're forced to do this if the "elsewhere" system is actually disconnected from the network and the "copy it to the other system" step involves copying the image file on to removable media.  If you're doing this at all regularly, though, or have more than one target system, you'll probably find setting up a local registry to be a good investment.